# VSCode Extension Host Terminated Unexpectedly OSX Catalina

Tags: visual-studio-code

Have recently updated to Catalina, since then have not been able to run/debug in VSCode. On start of VSCode I see a pop-up with message - extension host quit unexpectedly.

In developer tools I see message:

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib in /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an issue with mysql library installed on my mac. Nothing to do with vscode.
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH